# /var/lib/bluetooth changes do not persist in Fedora

Tags: fedora, bluetooth, mouse

I am experiencing the same problem outlined [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539122/34796), a laggy Bluetooth mouse (Logitech MX Anywhere 2S).  It seems a common solution is to edit `/var/lib/bluetooth/<device id>/<peripheral id>/info` and change the `ConnectionParameters.Latency` to 0.

When I try this with Fedora 35 (kernel 5.15), the values revert back to their original state after a few minutes and the mouse remains laggy.

What is overwriting these values in Fedora? Is there a proper way to change Bluetooth mouse latency, perhaps with the `bluetoothctl` tool?

Comment: Maybe a custom udev rule?

Comment: Thanks, but this is a fresh install. `/etc/udev/rules.d/` is empty.

Comment: I meant maybe you could write up a new rule "when you see this device, do this."

Comment: You can try editing some values under `[LE]` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, e.g. `ConnectionLatency=`. I'd post this as an answer, but in my very quick test it didn't work. Maybe you have better luck if you try unpairing and then repairing the device.